# How to make sudoreplay work?

Tags: command-line, sudo, log

I recently discovered `sudoreplay` whose [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man8/sudoreplay.8.html) says that it replays `sudo` session logs. But I am not sure how do I make it work. For whatever little commands I ran it kept on saying that `/var/log/sudo-io` doesn't exist.

```
$ sudoreplay -l user aditya command apt-get
sudoreplay: unable to open /var/log/sudo-io: No such file or directory

$ sudoreplay -l fromdate yesterday
sudoreplay: unable to open /var/log/sudo-io: No such file or directory
```

The man page says:

```
/var/log/sudo-io          The default I/O log directory.
```

It looks like I need to enable logging and it isn't enabled by default. What changes do I need to make to use `sudoreplay`?

Comment: Adding `-d /var/log`? (still not working for me, but well...)

Comment: @Rmano It doesn't show the error, but it doesn't display any other output as well. It just silently exits. BTW, I need to be `sudo` to run the command adding the `-d` argument.

Comment: Me too. `strace`-ing it seems that it tries to read a `/etc/sudo.conf` file that does not exist. I suppose that it is designed for some old version of sudo, and now things shuffled around.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add support for `sudoreplay`, we need to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file. For this, execute the following command:

```
$ sudo visudo
```

This would open the sudoers file for us. Then insert the following lines at the end of the file and save it:

```
Defaults log_output
Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
Defaults!/sbin/reboot !log_output
```

It will automatically create the directory `/var/log/sudo-io` when the
`visudo` command successfully exits AND you run `sudo su -`.

If it fails then that probably means that your version of `sudoers` package
is out of date. Upgrade the package and try again.

To run a `sudoreplay` session - who do you need to be? `root` ofcourse, so

```
$ sudo sudoreplay -l
Nov 28 11:48:35 2014 : chrthomp : TTY=/dev/pts/1 ; CWD=/home/chrthomp/DJS/2014/Nov ; USER=root ; TSID=000001 ; COMMAND=/bin/su -

$ sudo sudoreplay 000001
```

will replay the session at normal speed.

If you ever have problems with `sudoreplay` check that the `/var/log/sudo-io` folder exists. If it doesn't, you NEED to go and create the directory as `root`.

```
$ sudo mkdir -m 750 /var/log/sudo-io
```

Comment: Last 2 lines?  Copied from somewhere else?

Answer (score 3):

You need to go and create the directory as root.

```
$ mkdir -m 750 /var/log/sudo-io
```

then you need to enable logging in the sudoers file:
Add the following 3 lines........

```
Defaults log_output
Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
Defaults!/sbin/reboot !log_output
```